# how to fix 'conflicts with an already existing hostname' while cloning web app using Azure cloudshell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Scenario: You want to clone an app to another region, while configuring an Azure Resource Manager traffic manager profile that includes both apps.

Below are the commands I tried

```
$srcapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName SourceAzureResourceGroup -Name 
source-webapp

$destapp = New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName DestinationAzureResourceGroup -Name dest-webapp -Location "South Central US" -AppServicePlan DestinationAppServicePlan -SourceWebApp $srcapp -TrafficManagerProfileName newTrafficManagerProfile
```

the above commands fail with ""Creating app with backup from 'subscriptiondetailshere' failed: Detail: Hostname \'abc.xyz.companydomain.com\' conflicts with an already existing hostname. ExtendedCode: 04005"

FYI : the apps are hosted in standard app service plan. I did read documentation saying only the premium apps can be cloned but I was able to clone this particular app in standard plan through Azure Portal UI.

I want to be able to automate this using the ps. Any pointers are appreciated

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning

Comment: Hi ,Ivan Yang replied for your issue,is it helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

copied web app:

[image]

Traffic manager:[image]

---

**First**, azure web app clone does support `standard app service plan`. Here is a screenshot from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning):

[image]

**Second**, the code you're using is correct, I did a test at my side, it's working fine(The web app is copied from central us to west us, after copied, everything is working fine):

[image]

For the conflicting error, you should check in your destination resource group if there is a existing web app with that host name(you mentioned that you can copy from azure portal, maybe you didn't delete it when you were using code to copy it).

Comment: You were right the app was a webapp with same name was already existing, I had to dig it through PS to find out it was existing and deleted it. I tried to use the commands again after cleaning up, the command seems to clone the web app but the app cloning was never completed.

I can see the app under the app service plan / apps blade but not in the regular appservices blade. The app is missing type / resource group, take a look at here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFvF9.png

Also, Traffic manager got created but the endpoints were not added to it.

Comment: @user6163763 This should be another question. I did check it at my side. 1: endpoint is added in Traffic manager. 2: app is not missing type / resource group in app service plan, and I can see it in the regular app service blade(Please check the update section in my post). Can you try clone it to another region via this cmdlet?